# Use IN operator in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have `List<Candidate> Candidates, List<Seat> Seats`

The `Model` defined as shown below

```
 public class Seat
    {

         public string CollegeId { get; set; }
         public bool isFilled { get; set; }
         public string SeatType { get; set; }
         public string RollNumber { get; set; }
    }
     public class Candidate
     {
         public string RollNumber { get; set; }
         public bool isAllotted { get; set; }
         public string Quota { get; set; }
         public int CandidateRank { get; set; }
         public List<OptionPriority> SeatingPriorities { get; set; }

     }
     public class OptionPriority
     {
         public string CollegeId { get; set; }
         public int PriorityRank { get; set; }
     }
```

I need to filter `List<Seat>` from `List<Seat> Seats` where `Seats.CollegeId` IN List of CollegeID in SeatingPriorities.

Comment: One more note - [mutable structs are evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil). Consider to use classes for your data

Comment: Yes, they are! I changed it to class now. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// same as EXISTS
Seats.Where(s => SeatingPriorities.Any(sp => sp.CollegeId == s.CollegeId))
```

Also you can join seatings with seatings priorities:

```
// same as INNER JOIN
var prioritySeats = from s in Seats
                    join sp in SeatingPriorities
                         on s.CollegeId equals sp.CollegeId
                    select s;
```

NOTE: Both of queries above will not generate IN clause if you will execute them in LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities. IN is generated when you use Contains method of primitive types list:

```
var ids = SeatingPriorities.Select(sp => sp.CollegeId).ToList();
// same as IN
var prioritySeats = Seats.Where(s => ids.Contains(s.CollegeId));
```

Comment: Error 92 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AllotmentStruct.Seat>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Kiran\Desktop\entrance-kiran\AllotmetBL\FirstAllotmentBL.cs 34 30 AllotmentBL

Comment: @SubinJacob what type of parameters your `Where` method has? It should have overload with parameter of type `Func<TSource, bool>`. Ah I see, seating priorities is not simple list of id? Hold on

Comment: The `var ids = SeatingPriorities.Select(sp => sp.CollegeId).ToList();` is needed because Linq doesn't know EF doesn't know about SeatingPriorities. So its happy to pass a List of SeatingPriorities to EF from the Linq Query. EF obviously can't convert a list of SeatingPriorities into SQL.

Comment: Also of note, is that EF is unable to query cache WHERE IN queries. So you have a bit of a performance hit on the SQL generation here...FYI

Answer (score 2):

```
var results = source.Where(x => SeatingPriorities.Contains(x.CollegeId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Why default to calling `ToList`? And unless `SeatingPriorities` is an string, this won't work.

Comment: @GrantThomas To make sure query is executed only once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) to find out the matches like you do with `in`

```
var result = lstSeats.Where(s=>SeatingPriorities.Contains(s.CollegeId));
```

Comment: Error 92 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AllotmentStruct.Seat>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Kiran\Desktop\entrance-kiran\AllotmetBL\FirstAllotmentBL.cs 34 30 AllotmentBL

Answer (score 1):

Use `Contains` to achieve `IN` functionality in `LINQ`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Any`:

```
seats.Where(s => SeatingPriorities.Any(i => i.Id == s.CollegeId))
```

Since `Contains` only accepts an instance to compare (along with a possible `IEqualityComparer<T>`), which won't work if `OptionPriority` isn't an comparable to `CollegeId` (i.e. a `string`).